# Evenly distribute rotated text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a horizontal menu with rotated text (let's say -50deg).
My code looks as follow:

```css
 .menuItem {
   text-align: right;
   margin-top: 3vh;
   list-style-type: none;
   display:inline-block;
  }

  .menuButton{
      text-align: right;
      background:none;
      padding: 0;
      border:none;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(310deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(310deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(310deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(310deg);
      transform: rotate(310deg);
      -webkit-transform-origin:100%;
      -moz-transform-origin:100%;
      -ms-transform-origin:100%;
      -o-transform-origin:100%;
      transform-origin:100% ;
  }
```

```html
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menuItem">
          <button class="menuButton" id="newsButton">Button</button>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem">
          <button class="menuButton" id="aboutButton">LoooooooongButton</button>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem">
          <button class="menuButton" id="contactsButton">ShortButton</button>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem">
          <button class="menuButton" id="otherStuffButton">LoooooooooooooongestButton</button>
        </li>

      </ul>
```

I've already managed to rotate each button, to right-align the text, and to put them horizontal, the only problem I face is that I can't manage to evenly distribute the text, since the buttons with longer text will be farer from their left sibling than those with a short text.
What's the best solution for this problem?
Thank you all.

**UPDATE**

I've just written a simple script through javascript which gets the container width and distributes evenly the buttons:

```js
var menuWidth = $('.menu').width();
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".menuItem");
for (var element of elements){
    let ind = $(element).index();
    $(element).css("left", $(element).height()-$(element).width()+(menuWidth/(elements.length))*ind);
}
```

Obviously the trick here is to assign position: absolute to all menu items and position: relative to menu.
Thank you all, guys ;)

Comment: Are they dynamically created? Because if that's not a requirement, you could easily use the IDs to adjust as needed. Otherwise, it's a lot more tricky.

Comment: nope they are not, would you suggest to assign position: absolute to all the menu elements and then manually give them their left position?

Comment: In that case, yes. I would definitely recommend just doing something like that as it will save a LOT of headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty tricky because a transform is a *purely visual effect* and does not affect the actual position of elements.

Generally, one solution is to size the element as required and position the content absolutely.

Kind of like this:

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  margin: 4em;
}
.menuItem {
  text-align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: rotate(310deg);
  flex: 0 0 1.2em;
  height: 1.4em;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}
.menuButton {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menuItem">
    <button class="menuButton" id="newsButton">Button</button>
  </li>
  <li class="menuItem">
    <button class="menuButton" id="aboutButton">LoooooooongButton</button>
  </li>
  <li class="menuItem">
    <button class="menuButton" id="contactsButton">ShortButton</button>
  </li>
  <li class="menuItem">
    <button class="menuButton" id="otherStuffButton">LoooooooooooooongestButton</button>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Now this has downsides as the size of the `li` has no dynamic size but I leave this here as a general guide.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I realized that problem was that, I have spent the entire afternoon trying to figure out how to solve it :D